# Align all HTML elements in One Line Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a question, I have align all elements in one line.

Actually it should look like this.[image]

I created this with the help of creating tables and adding each ProgressBar as Div ELements inside table cells. For some reason, this is not working in IE 7.

So, I wanted to create the html using Div Elements alone without any tables. Now it looks like this:

[image]

Can you please tell me what I am missing?

Here is the CSS code:

```
div.coverage-container {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  width:370px;
   height:30px;   
}  

div.progressbar-content{
width: 95px;    
text-align: center;
float:left; 
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
 }


div.progressbar-maindiv {
background-color: #DAE2E3;
border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;    
margin: 3px -9px 3px 114px;
padding: 3px;
width: 75px;
float:left;
 }


.progressbar-percentage {
background-color: #F23F54;
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
height: 15px;
width: 80.00%;
 }

 .progressbar-chart-icon {       margin-right: 5px; float:right;       text-align: center;     }
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
 <div class="coverage-container">   
<div class="progressbar-content">
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>

    </div>
    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />            
</div>

<div class="progressbar-content">
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon">
</div>

<div class="progressbar-content">
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: FYI, the <center> tag has been deprecated.

Comment: hi Derek, if <center> is depracted, is there any other way i can create progressbar with center?

Comment: Use CSS, text-align:center;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Q9Cv/

The primary thing I did was float all your items left, and I re-ordered where your icon is in your HTML to come before your progress bar.  I 0'd out all margin space on the progress bar itself.  I also set the height of your "blocks" to the height of your container, and changed the border around the blocks to just have border-right.  This way there aren't double borders anywhere.

You'll want to mess with the widths a little bit to adjust them to your needs... Just be sure you dont make the widths too small, or you'll break it and the progress bar will fall to the next line.  (do your math basically)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="coverage-container">   

<div class="progressbar-content">

    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />    
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END BLOCK -->

<div class="progressbar-content">

    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />    
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END BLOCK -->

<div class="progressbar-content">

    <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends"  src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />    
    <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
        <div class="progressbar-percentage">
            <center>80%</center>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END BLOCK -->


</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.coverage-container {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    width:370px;
    height:30px;   
    overflow: visible;
    clear: both;
}  

div.progressbar-content {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}


div.progressbar-maindiv {
    background-color: #DAE2E3;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 75px;
    float:left;
}


.progressbar-percentage {
    background-color: #F23F54;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 80.00%;
}

.progressbar-chart-icon {
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is the solution I was looking for. Border Radius and border opacity does not work in IE 7.. Is there any way We can fix it. But apart from that, Everything looks fine.

Comment: You can use Modernizr to help support for border-radius and RGBA values. http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: Make sure you read the documentation on how to use it properly.  I also suggest you download a "customized" variation of it, that contains only what you need.  This will save on file-space and consequently, load times. ;)

Comment: Yes, You are right, Just creating modernizer with 2 functionalities, it generated 9Kb of file.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/RKADY/

HTML

```
<div class="coverage-container">
    <div class="progressbar-content">
        <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends" src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />
        <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
            <div class="progressbar-percentage">
                <center>80%</center>
            </div>
        </div>
          <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends" src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />
        <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
            <div class="progressbar-percentage">
                <center>80%</center>
            </div>
        </div>
                <img width="21" height="21" title="Get Trends" src="http:/localhost/newccft2/Content/images/chart-graph-icon.png" class="progressbar-chart-icon" />
        <div class="progressbar-maindiv">
            <div class="progressbar-percentage">
                <center>80%</center>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.coverage-container {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    width:700px;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.progressbar-content {
    width: 95px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    display: inline;

}
div.progressbar-maindiv {
    background-color: #DAE2E3;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    margin: 3px 9px 20px -10px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
}
.progressbar-percentage {
    background-color: #F23F54;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 80.00%;

}
.progressbar-chart-icon {
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;  
}
```

Comment: hi, Your solution did not borders for individual Div ELements. I think the below answer has it. Thanks for the quick response. You saved my day :)